# I can't build my react with boostrap problem about css-loader

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack, bootstrap-4, webpack-4

My react index.js import bootstrap, I using Webpack 4

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './assets/css/index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

When i run build, This error message

> ERROR in ./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css 6:3
>   Module parse failed: Unexpected token (6:3)
>   You may need an
>   appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are
>   configured to process this file. See
>   https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders

```
module: {
   ...
   {
      test: /\.css$/,
      exclude: /(node_modules)/,
      use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
   },
   ...
}
```

Thank your for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You  excluding your node_modules causing this problem remove it from wabpack configuration.

```
module: {
   ...
   {
      test: /\.css$/,
      use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
   },
   ...
}
```

Comment: let me know if you have any query.

Comment: It correct, but my vendors file WARNING in asset size limit: The following asset(s) exceed the recommended size limit (97.7 KiB).
This can impact web performance.
Assets: 
  vendors/c_b29.42a0a9ab895548ac03cb.js (294 KiB)

Comment: it isn't load into index.html, Thank you i'm begin learning about react and webpack 2 days ago